# Как изменить свойство отдельного элемента в стиле?

Tags: c#, wpf, blend

Добрый день. Написал простенький стиль для кнопки, хотел уже сделать изменение цвета кнопки при наведении, но не пойму, как обратиться к цвету прямоугольника.
Вот код разметки:

```
    <Style x:Key="SettingsButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Rect" Fill="#FF00002E"/>
                        <Path Data="M0,10 L20,10 20,12 0,12 z M0,5 L20,5 20,7 0,7 z M0,0 L20,0 20,2 0,2 z" Fill="#FFE8E8E8" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="12" Margin="0,0,0,0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="20"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">

                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">

                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">

                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задайте нужному элементу имя, с помощью `x:Name`.
Далее при нужном событии обратитесь к этому элементу, через `TargetName`:

```
<Setter TargetName="MyName" Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
```